# What is the simplest way to draw triangle gradients using OpenGL es 2.x

Tags: android, opengl-es

I was running my program on an android phone that uses OpenGL 1.x, and to generate triangular gradients I used this code:

```
    gl11.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorPointerShadow);
    gl11.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
```

However my newer phone that uses OpenGL 2.0 is like uh uh, no you di'in, and then crashes. So how do I draw a basic gradient on a triangle? Can it be done without getting all up into shaders' business? Thanks for reading!

Comment: Yes, you will need a shader. There are plenty of resources on the net for learning about how to use them.

Comment: Also rendering simple triangle gradients requires only very few lines of shader code. But leaves a lot of room for being creative and I can only recommend getting familiar with shaders, on basic level at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL ES 2.0 is not backward compatible with 1.1.  You need to write shaders, but don't be scared.  Your vertex shader can be very simple, like this:

```
attribute vec4 Pos, Color; // vertex shader inputs
varying vec4 vColor;       // vertex shader output
uniform mat4 MVP;          // model-view-projection matrix
void main() {
    gl_Position = MVP * Pos;
    vColor = Color;
}
```

And your fragment shader can be even more simple:

```
varying lowp vec4 vColor;   // vertex shader output
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vColor;
}
```

If you assign a unique color to each triangle corner, you'll see a gradient.

Comment: Thanks. The lack of simple codes like this one makes the OpenGL ES 2.0 learning curve even steeper.